# How to prevent Entity Framework multiple model generators from overwriting each others files?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In a single `.csproj` project with multiple `.emdx` (`ADO.NET Entity Data Model` > `EF Designer from database`) how do I prevent them overwriting each others' files when there is table name collision (the `Bar.cs` in the example below)? Is there an option a la Service Reference generator or me precreating and putting them each in its own folder the only option?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have overlapping class names then they would have to be in different namespaces. As such just put your edmx files in the appropriate folders e.g. `/Foo1NamesSpace/foo1.edmx` `/Foo2NamesSpace/foo2.edmx`

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks, yes, I was wondering if there is any other way I can force it to create it own folders like Service Reference does and not pollute my Solution Explorer.